# I'd like to know what is internally happening in this code?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, printf

I'd like to know the internal processing of this code.

```
char arr[] = "cat";
*arr = 'b';
printf("%s",arr);
```

Here in this code how is `c` in the array overridden by `b`?

```
Output : bat
```

Comment: *arr is equivalent to arr[0].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it helps to understand, `*arr` is the same as `*(&arr[0])`<sup>Note below</sup>, i.e., it refers to the value stored at index 0.

You are simply assigning a new value to it.

Graphically:

```
char arr[] = "cat";
```

is

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+     
|  c    |   a    |   t    |   \0   |             
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
  arr[0]  arr[1]   arr[2]   arr[3]
```

and, after

```
*arr = 'b';   // which is practically same as arr[0] = 'b';
```

is

```
+-------+--------+--------+--------+   
|  b    |   a    |   t    |   \0   |             
+-------+--------+--------+--------+
  arr[0]  arr[1]   arr[2]   arr[3]
```

Note:

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.1

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, the `_Alignof` operator, or the
>   unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has
>   type *‘‘array of type’’* is converted to an expression with type *‘‘pointer to type’’* that points
>   to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. [...]

Comment: @ChristianGibbons Updated